# how to upload base64 files in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, base64, angular2-services

I'm trying to upload files in base64 format but it has not worked. I do not understand what is wrong, this is the error that throws

this is the function

```
private headerMedia = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/base64"});

    uploadMedia(base64, process, id): any {        
        let ruta: string = "http://route";
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headerMedia});       

            return this.http
            .post(ruta, base64, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => base64)
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method help you.

Create a Directory in your Angular Project

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.ngFileModel);
            var isMultiple = attrs.multiple;
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var values = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < element[0].files.length; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = (function (i) {
                        return function(e) {
                            var value = {
                                lastModified: changeEvent.target.files[i].lastModified,
                                lastModifiedDate: changeEvent.target.files[i].lastModifiedDate,
                                name: changeEvent.target.files[i].name,
                                size: changeEvent.target.files[i].size,
                                type: changeEvent.target.files[i].type,
                                data: e.target.result
                            };
                            values.push(value);
                        }

                    })(i);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[i]);
                }


                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (isMultiple) {
                        modelSetter(scope, values);
                    } else {
                        modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

use ng-file-model in your input tag

```
 <input accept="image/*" ng-file-model="photo" type="file" multiple/>
```

Now upload it using $http.post

```
 $http.post('/api/uploadPic',{photo:photo}).
    success(function (data, status) {
       //perform action after upload
    });
```

I hope this help you

Comment: This looks like AngularJS code, but the question tags are for Angular 2.